# Python: Read and edit a list in a text file

Tags: python

I am really new to Python (only started coding 2 weeks ago and still getting use to the terminology) and would love some help understanding lists and text files.

I have a text file that stores a list (I have also read it is called an array - is that correct?) of car details e.g.

```
[1,Nissan, Red, 5, 2017]  
[2,Ford, Blue, 8, 2012]  
[3,Nissan, Yellow, 9, 2001]
```

My first question relates to "Are these lists?". Are they the same thing as coding:

```
Car1 = [1,Nissan,Red, 2017]
Car2 = [2,Ford, Blue, 2012]
```

If the text file is the same as above - How do I call the data into `Car1`, `Car2` etc.?

My second question would be how would I say search for car '2' and then change the year, say from 2012 to 2016?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why not use `pickle` to store an object binary into a file?

Comment: What you're looking at is called serialization. You're trying to find the right way to serialize some data. An array is not a list, but since arrays are the most commonly-used collection in many languages and lists are the most commonly-used collection in Python, people know what you mean when you say array (even if they also know you're wrong). The objects you've written there would be better-off as tuples though `(1, "Nissan", "Red", 2017)`, since they're heterogeneous (`int`, `str`, `str`, `int`, `int`)

Comment: If you've got a ton of these and you're using them for a non-toy project, now would be the correct time to learn to do serialization correctly. Look at the `sqlite3` stdlib module. Look up how to create a strong database structure and maintain it correctly.

Comment: If you've only got a few, or if this is a toy project, look at storing state as a pickled object. the `pickle` stdlib module does serialization and deserialization, as do other modules such as the more standard `json`.

Comment: If you're doing this as an exercise to better-understand the language, know that This Will Be Hard. Sanitizing input and getting helpful well-formed data out of arbitrary input is one of the hardest parts of programming (aside from naming things and off by one errors ;-) so be prepared to beat your head against the wall for a while. If those were well-formed lines (`[1, "Nissan", "Red", 5, 2017]`) you could use `ast.literal_eval(line)`, but since they're not (no quotes around your strings) you've got to write something yourself.

Comment: If you have `[1,Nissan, Red, 5, 2017]` in a text file you can call it a list if you want, but it is just text not a python `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists and arrays are synonymous.

**Question 1**

Generally when data is stored, it is stored as a delimited text file. That is where the data entries are separated by some special character. For example, if a file contained

```
1,Nissan,Red,5,2017
```

Then this would be a comma delimited text file (csv). You don't normally want to store data as it would be formatted by a particular language as in your example.

**Question 2**

Dictionaries in Python are probably needed so that your data would be indexed by names rather than positions. If you were to store your data as:

```
cars = [
  {
    "index":1,
    "brand":"Nissan",
    "color":"Red",
    "year": 2017
  },{
    "index":2,
    "brand":"Ford",
    "color":"Blue",
    "year": 2012
  }
]
```

Then you could set `cars[1]["year"] = 2016`

This format will also allow you to use json formatting when writing to a text file. You could also serialize/pickle your data or use a database as other commenters have said.

Comment: Character delimited text is just _one_ way to store data in files. There's literally infinitely many other possibilities. (Not all of them practical, of course.)

Comment: Lists and arrays are not synonymous. Note that we do have [proper arrays in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) and that they're not lists.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally chose [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in this case. You could easily define each one of them as simple as:

```
{"no": 1, "maker": "Ford", "doors": "4", "year": 2016}
```

Storing and reading dicts from a file is fairly easy with `pickle` or the built-in [json library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)